# How should I differentiate $\frac{\left|x\right|^3}{x^2-4}$

Tags: functions, derivatives

I'm trying to find Maxima and minima points of the following function:
$$\frac{\left|x\right|^3}{x^2-4}$$

How should I differentiate it?

Comment: First, apply the division rule.

Comment: You can split into two parts, noting that $|x|^3=-x^3$ when $x$ is negative. Better is to note the symmetry across the $y$-axis, so if you know max/min in $[0,\infty)$, you can write down without further work the max/min for $(-\infty,0]$.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**: calculate the derivative separately for $x\geq 0$ and $x<0$.